# Sales person performance prediction

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I am trying to predict/forecast salesperson performance weekly, monthly, quarterly, and yearly based on the products that they sold over 3 years. As part of this effort, I grouped their number of units sold by the state, location, stores, product types, and sale dates.

By using this information I grouped their id and month of sales and number of units sold. Example data is shown below.

For ARIMA modeling, does this format work well enough to predict/forecast salesperson performance weekly, monthly, quartely, and yearly?

```
Id      Month   Units
65381   201703  467.0
65381   201710  3.0
65381   201712  6.0
65381   201803  20.0
65381   201805  2.0
65381   201807  20.0
65381   201812  16.0
65381   201904  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of fitting a linear model to each salesperson by week, month and quarter. You'll need to extract the week, month and quarter from the date using the lubridate package.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

#create fake data
n_var <- 50
id <- sample(x=seq(from=1,to=4),size=n_var,replace=TRUE)
dte <- sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2019/01/01'), by="day"), size=n_var)
sales <- runif(min=0,max=25,n=n_var)

sales_data <- data.frame(id,dte,sales) %>% 
  mutate(
    weeknumber=week(dte),
    month=month(dte),
    qtr=quarter(dte)

  )

#fit an OLS model
ols_model <- sales_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(
    week_model=list(lm(sales~weeknumber)),
    month_model=list(lm(sales~month)),
    qtr_model=list(lm(sales~qtr))
    )

#extract coefficients
ols_model$week_model[[1]]$coefficients
ols_model$month_model[[1]]$coefficients
ols_model$qtr_model[[1]]$coefficients

ols_model$week_model[[2]]$coefficients
ols_model$month_model[[2]]$coefficients
ols_model$qtr_model[[3]]$coefficients

#simple version on one id
df <- sales_data %>% 
  filter(id==1)

mod <- lm(sales~qtr,data=df)
mod$coefficients
```

Comment: thanks for the sample code. Would you mind to share some examples in python?

Comment: Would it be possible to integrate/send outputs of ARIMA with a web interface? something like coefficients/weights in ML models.

Comment: Sorry I don't python well enough to convert the code, but take a look at this site https://www.xavierdupre.fr/app/pyensae/helpsphinx/notebooks/r2python.html . I'm sure you could integrate with a web page, best to ask another question

Comment: Sure,will post a new query on the stastical modeling integration with a web.